# How to prevent importing class defined in the same file?

Tags: kotlinpoet

I need the following generated code:

```kotlin
import DoesntMatter

class MyClass {}

fun DoesntMatter.function(i: MyClass.() -> Unit) {}
```

I have written the following:

```java
FunSpec.Builder funBuilder = FunSpec.builder(funName);
funBuilder.receiver(new ClassName("", "DoesntMatter")); // ok, i need that import
funBuilder.addParameter("i", LambdaTypeName.get(
  new ClassName("", "MyClass"), // i do not need that import cause i declare this class in my file
  new ArrayList<>(),
  TypeNames.UNIT));

TypeSpec.Builder typeBuilder = TypeSpec.classBuilder("MyClass"); // here i declare class

FileSpec.Builder fileBuilder = FileSpec.builder(packageName, model.getName())
  .addType(typeBuilder.build())
  .addFunction(funBuilder.build());
```

But it generates import that i dont need:

```kotlin
import DoesntMatter
import MyClass

class MyClass {}

fun DoesntMatter.function(i: MyClass.() -> Unit) {}
```

And i get compile error. Workaround is to split function declaration and class declaration into two different files, but it is not really pretty as intented.

Is there any hack to not produce uselss import or where is my code wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the output I get when running your code with `packageName == ""`:

```
import kotlin.Unit

public class MyClass

public fun DoesntMatter.function(i: MyClass.() -> Unit) {
}
```

Neither `MyClass` nor `DoesntMatter` are imported, since they're in the same package.

And here's what I get when I set `packageName` to a non-empty string, e.g. `com.squareup.kotlinpoet`:

```
package com.squareup.kotlinpoet

import DoesntMatter
import MyClass
import kotlin.Unit

public class MyClass

public fun DoesntMatter.function(i: MyClass.() -> Unit) {
}
```

Both types are imported, since they're declared in a different package than this file. You're basically redeclaring `MyClass` in this file, but referencing the one in the default package in your function declaration, since the correct `ClassName` for this one is `ClassName("com.squareup.kotlinpoet", "MyClass")`.

So make sure the package names check out to avoid unwanted imports. KotlinPoet treats `packageName == ""` as "default package", not "same package", so you can't rely on omitting the package name to avoid an import.

Also, please make sure you're using the latest version of the library, which is 1.15.3 at the time of writing.